# Need education regarding HttpApplicationState of ASP.net

Tags: asp.net-3.5, session-state

Today I've got confused with 2 issues related to the HttpApplicationState of ASP.net. My questions are as follows

1. If I use a StateServer for my session management (the out proc session management stuff that I want to use for my web garden deployment), is it safe assuming that the **HttpApplicationState (I am accessing via System.Web.UI.Page.Application property) is also stored inside the StateServer** just as Session? So if my workerprocess A writes a value "10" into the Page.Application, another request running in workerprocess  B at some point later must see this "10" for the same key- is it correct?
2. One of my fellow developer told me that he found in his test, in a StateServer scenario, **if he has 100 key-value entries inserted into the Page.Session then when he tries to read any of the key from a different request, the workerprocess brings the entire 100 entries into the active workerprocess memory space and then serves the key that was actually asked by the request.** is it true?

It would be greatly appreciate if someone could help me to remove my confusions on this regard.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. StateServer supports Session state only,  Application state is limited to the AppDomain.
2. The StateServer stores a serialisation of a Session.  It has no way to know how access a specific key value.  When accessed the session is re-hydrated into the application requiring it and is used as normal session data for the duration of the request.

Comment: Re #1:  This also means that if you have WebGarden turned on, each instance of the webgarden has its own Application state.

Answer (score 0):

1. As far as I know the out of process state server does not store HttpApplicationState data. You could test this easily to be sure, but I doubt that it does.
2. I don't think this is true either. The session store is basically a hashtable. Looking up a single key in a hashtable should only return the associated value. You shouldn't see the behaviour you describe. Again, you should be able to test this easily.